# How to access Active Directory via Proxy in java?

Tags: java, ldap, proxy-server

I have application say 'X' which is behind proxy server. From this application I need to call Active directory say 'Y'. 
Currently we are able to make LDAP call successfully between X and Y when proxy server is not there. But same LDAP call fails when proxy server exists between X and Y. Because our corporate proxy server won't allow communication using ldap/ldaps (i.e 389/636) ports. Here X and Y exists on different networks. 
Can anyone suggest any framework/API/procedure/architecture to address this situation.

Answer (score 1):

We can implement this using HTTP tunneling. The following are the two ways to implement it. 
1.HTTP tunneling without using CONNECT method
2.HTTP tunneling using CONNECT method.
I've given here a detailed explanation on how I've implemented the second solution here 
https://dheerajgopali.wordpress.com/2015/08/17/how-to-access-an-on-premise-active-directory-from-cloud-using-java/

Comment: this answer is really useful and working , Please correct the example environment.put("java.naming.ldap.factory.socket", "com.proxy.CustomSSLSocketFactory");